# How to change back to default toolbar navigationicon

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar

after changing the toolbar navigationicon using

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

I can't get it work on to work switch back to the default (burger) icon:

```
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.navigationIcon};
TypedArray ta = myContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
Drawable drawableFromTheme = ta.getDrawable(0 /* index */);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawableFromTheme);
ta.recycle();
```

Comment: Are you using drawerToggle?

Comment: here is what i tried by switching myactivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
and
myactivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
and then call 
ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
the burger icon does come back but it takes like a minute for the icon to refresh, any idea why that happened?

Comment: What you need to do is mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false) to show back icon, mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); to show default icon.

Comment: don't call the syncState()

Comment: The best way is that creating custom toolbar.